# How to split a string and define parents and child using python?

Tags: python, json, split

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
    "Example0/Example1/File1.py": {
        "Example0/Element_1/File1.py": null,
        "ExampleA/ExampleB/File2.py": 0.0769,
    },
    "ExampleA/ExampleB/File2.py": {
        "Example0/Example1/File1.py": 1.0,
        "ExampleA/ExampleB/File2.py": null,
    }
}
```

Until now I only had to split the "Files.py" from the folders, but as a new task I will have to split it every time a `"/"` appears and store it so I can write this information as one parameter of an XML file where every element is listed and, for example "File1.py" would be a child of "Example1" and this would be a child of "Example0".

The code I was using until now is this:

```
arch = {}
for key in json_dict:
    splitted = key.rsplit("/", 1)
    parent = splitted[0]
    child = key
    if parent in arch:
        arch[parent].append(child)
    else:
        arch[parent] = [child]
```

The idea is to change the code in something that results in an output like:

```
parent0 = Example0
parent1 = Example0/Example1
child = key
```

But not limited to two parents, as it is possible to have something like:

```
ExampleA/ExampleB/ExampleC/ExampleD/File0.py
```

Where the expected output would be:

```
parent0 = ExampleA
parent1 = ExampleA/ExampleB
parent2 = ExampleA/ExampleB/ExampleC
parent3 = ExampleA/ExampleB/ExampleC/ExampleD

child = key
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: Why don't you use `key.split("/")` instead of `key.rsplit("/", 1)` and then iterate over the parts? Btw. you could also use [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath) and its methods.

Comment: Could you please [add to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71705081/edit) how the expected output for your example input should look like (until the expected output ins't clear, there's a huge potential that users willing to help you are wasting their time).

Comment: I had the output as comment here, edited it and put into the question, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how your expected output should look like:

> where every element is listed and, for example "File1.py" would be a child of "Example1" and **this** would be a child of "Example0"

and

> Where the expected output would be:
>
> ```
> parent0 = ExampleA
> parent1 = ExampleA/ExampleB
> parent2 = ExampleA/ExampleB/ExampleC
> parent3 = ExampleA/ExampleB/ExampleC/ExampleD
>
> child = key
> ```

seem a bit different? The best would be if you would include the explicit expected output for your example in in the question - i.e. the expected `arch` dictionary.

Here's a suggestion:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import PurePath as Path

arch = defaultdict(list)
for key in json_dict:
    for path in list(Path(key).parents)[:-1]:
        arch[str(path)].append(key)
```

Output for

```
json_dict = {
    "Ex0/F1.py": {"Some content": None,},
    "Ex0/Ex1/F1.py": {"Some content": None,},
    "ExA/ExB/F2.py": {"Some content": 1.0,},
    "ExA/ExB/ExC/ExD/F0.py": {"Some content": None}
}
```

would be

```
{'Ex0': ['Ex0/F1.py', 'Ex0/Ex1/F1.py'],
 'Ex0/Ex1': ['Ex0/Ex1/F1.py'],
 'ExA': ['ExA/ExB/F2.py', 'ExA/ExB/ExC/ExD/F0.py'],
 'ExA/ExB': ['ExA/ExB/F2.py', 'ExA/ExB/ExC/ExD/F0.py'],
 'ExA/ExB/ExC': ['ExA/ExB/ExC/ExD/F0.py'],
 'ExA/ExB/ExC/ExD': ['ExA/ExB/ExC/ExD/F0.py']}
```

If you don't like to use `Path` then this should produce the same output:

```
from collections import defaultdict

arch = defaultdict(list)
for key in json_dict:
    path = key
    while True:
        if "/" not in path:
            break
        path = path.rsplit("/", maxsplit=1)[0]
        arch[path].append(key)
```

Is this what you are looking for? Or is it more like

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import PurePath as Path

arch = defaultdict(list)
for key in json_dict:
    parents = [key] + list(Path(key).parents)[:-1]
    for child, parent in zip(parents[:-1], parents[1:]):
        arch[str(parent)].append(str(child))
```

```
{'Ex0': ['Ex0/F1.py', 'Ex0/Ex1'],
 'Ex0/Ex1': ['Ex0/Ex1/F1.py'],
 'ExA/ExB': ['ExA/ExB/F2.py', 'ExA/ExB/ExC'],
 'ExA': ['ExA/ExB', 'ExA/ExB'],
 'ExA/ExB/ExC/ExD': ['ExA/ExB/ExC/ExD/F0.py'],
 'ExA/ExB/ExC': ['ExA/ExB/ExC/ExD']}
```

... ?

Comment: This solves my problem, the first two solutions you suggested are the right ones. thank you!